# Selecting multiple columns in data frame using partial column name

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame, DF, and the column names all contain color names:

```
red_balloons green_balloons red_balls blue_balls green_hats red_horses yellow_things
```

What I would like to do is select multiple columns based on more than one color name. I can select one column at a time like this:

```
grep("red", colnames(DF))
```

But I cannot figure out or find out how to select multiple columns. I tried this:

```
grep(c("red", "blue"), colnames(DF))
```

But got the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In grep(c("mean()", "std()"), colnames(L21), value = FALSE) :
   argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "|" for "or" in grep

```
grep("red|blue", DF, value=T)
# [1] "red_balloons" "red_balls"    "blue_balls"   "red_horses"
```

Comment: That worked. You know, I thought I had tried that, but what I had actually done was grep("red"|"blue", DF, value=T). Thanks.

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)

Comment: Is there also an option to use an object in stead of typing all names yourself?