# Selecting rows in data.table on the basis of a substring match to any of multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this one, but with many more columns:

```
library(data.table)
the_dt = data.table(DetailCol1=c("Deets1","Deets2","Deets3","Deets4"), DetailCol2 = c("MoreDeets1","MoreDeets2","MoreDeets3","MoreDeets4"), DataCol1=c("ARP","AARPP","ABC","ABC"), DataCol2=c("ABC","ABC","ABC","ARPe"), DataCol3 = c("ABC", "ARP", "ABC","ABC"))
```

I want to retrieve DetailCol1 of only those rows that contain a match to the string 'ARP'.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630335/how-to-select-r-data-table-rows-based-on-substring-match-a-la-sql-like#) was useful in pointing me to `like`, but I'm still not sure how do this for multiple columns, especially if there are dozens of columns in which I would like to search.

For instance, this is how I could search within DataCol1
`the_dt[DataCol1 %like% 'ARP',DetailCol1]`, but how would I conduct the same search in DataCols 1-100?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250878/selecting-multiple-columns-in-data-frame-using-partial-column-name) may help.  Refers to [grep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)

Comment: If you are applying this %like%  on all the 'DataCol's , in this example, what would be the expected output

Comment: Varontron, grepping the colnames() might be useful if I can avoid having to use with=F in the data.table...

Comment: Akrun, in the code above, I would get deets1 and deets2. Applying the same search across all data columns should also return deets 4, if that makes sense.

Comment: Is it kind of like the matches that are common from all the searches

Comment: you might want to `melt` your `data.table` so that you can just search one column...

Comment: I want to get all of the detailCol1 rows for which a match exists in that row in any column.

Comment: In your first DataCol1, 'ARP', match is at position1 &  2, 2nd in 4th and 3rd in 2nd.

Comment: Sorry. I am not at my computer right now. Searching just datacol1 should give me just row2, you are correct. But I want to search more than just datacol 1

Comment: In your examples, the 'datacol1' 1st element is "ARP" and 2nd is "AARPP".  So the `%like%` gives both 1st and 2nd match as TRUE.  I posted a solution below, please check if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the columns to compare in `.SDcol`, loop through it with `lapply`, convert it to logical using `%like%`, check whether there is at least one TRUE per each row using `Reduce`, use that to subset the elements from 'DetailCol1'.

```
the_dt[the_dt[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%like%`, "ARP")),
                       .SDcols= DataCol1:DataCol3], DetailCol1]
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks, akrun! Reduce is a very cool trick!

Comment: @Atticus29  Thanks for the feedback.  Yes, it is a convenient function for this situation.